# Python module importing issue

Tags: python

I won't post the code, I'll only quote relevant parts, since it's a bit long.

So, I have a main .py file where I defined some classes. When I run the file and use the procedures defined in the classes, everything works fine. Now, I want to create a main .py file which will import the file with all the definitions, i.e. "from some_file import *". Now, when I execute this file, one procedure doesn't work and gives the NameError (global name some_attribute is not defined). Now, this procedure is defined in one of the classes, and uses an attibute created inside another of the classes. For some reason, this reference doesn't work and I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Here, I'll give the code from the "main" file:

```
from fem_obj import *
nd = Node()
nd.nodegen(1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4)
el = Element()
el.elgen(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3)
```

fem_obj is the file with my classes Node and Element. nd and el are of course their instances. nodegen and elgen are methods. Now, the elgen method inside the other file refers to an attribute which is created after the nodegen procedure is called. And there i get a name error. I.e., the elgen method uses nd.nodes, which is a list which is created by the nodegen method.

I hope this is clear enough, I can post the code of the other file if necessary. Thanks in advance for any help.

OK, here's the code for fem_obj:

```
from math import hypot, sqrt
from Tkinter import *

class Node:

    def __init__(self):  
        self.nodes = []
        self.nodenum = 0

    def nodegen(self, slabel, dlabel, sx, sy, dx, dy, num):    
        for i in range(1, num + 1):                
            label = slabel + (i - 1)*dlabel
            if self.nodecheck(label) == True:
                return "Node %s already exists!" %label            
            self.nodes = self.nodes + [[label, (sx + (i - 1)*dx, sy + (i - 1)*dy), (0, 0, 0)]]
            self.nodenum += 1

    def nodegenf(self, slabel, dlabel, sx, dx, num):
        f = lambda x: sqrt(1 - x**2)
        for i in range(1, num + 1):                
            label = slabel + (i - 1)*dlabel
            if self.nodecheck(label) == True:
                return "Node %s already exists!" %label            
            self.nodes = self.nodes + [[label, (sx + (i - 1)*dx, f(sx + (i - 1)*dx)), (0, 0, 0)]]
            self.nodenum += 1      

    def nodeadd(self, label, sx, sy):
        if self.nodecheck(label) == True:
            return "Node %s already exists!" %label
        self.nodes = self.nodes + [[label, (sx, sy), (0, 0, 0)]]
        self.nodenum += 1        

    def nodedel(self, label):
        if self.nodecheck(label) == False:
            return "Node %s does not exist!" %label
        for i in el.elements:
            if label in i[1]:
                return "Node %s attached to element %s!" %(label, i[0])
        for i in self.nodes:
            if label == i[0]:
                self.nodes.remove(i)
        self.nodenum -= 1                

    def nodecheck(self, label):
        for i in self.nodes:
            if label == i[0]:
                return True
        return False

    def noderes(self, label, u, v, r):
        if self.nodecheck(label) == False:
            return "Node %s does not exist!" %label
        for i in self.nodes:
            if label == i[0]:
                i[2] = (u, v, r)       

    def nodelist(self):
        if self.nodes == []:
            return "No nodes defined!"
        print "\n"
        print "NUMBER OF NODES: ", self.nodenum
        print "\n"
        print "NODE   COORDINATES   RESTRAINTS"
        print "----   -----------   ----------"
        print "\n"
        for i in self.nodes:
            print i[0], "   ", i[1], "      ", i[2]


class Element:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
        self.elnum = 0

    def elgen(self, slabel, dlabel, snl, enl, sndl, endl, num):
        for i in range(1, num + 1):                
            label = slabel + (i - 1)*dlabel 
            if self.elcheck(label) == True:
                return "Element %s already exists!" %label
            if self.elements != []:
                for j in self.elements:
                    if j[1] == (snl + (i - 1)*sndl, enl + (i - 1)*endl):
                        return "Element %s endnodes already taken!" %label
            hlplst = []
            for j in nd.nodes: # nd reference
                hlplst = hlplst + [j[0]]
            if snl + (i - 1)*sndl not in hlplst:
                return "Node %s does not exist" %(snl + (i - 1)*sndl)
            if enl + (i - 1)*endl not in hlplst:
                return "Node %s does not exist" %(enl + (i - 1)*endl)                             
            self.elements = self.elements + [[label, (snl + (i - 1)*sndl, enl + (i - 1)*endl)]]
            self.elnum +=1
        self.ellen()

    def elcheck(self, label):
        for i in self.elements:
            if label == i[0]:
                return True
        return False

    def eladd(self, label, snl, enl):
        if self.elcheck(label) == True:
            return "Element %s already exists!" %label
        if self.elements != []:
            for j in self.elements:
                if j[1] == (snl, enl):        
                    return "Endnodes already taken by element %s!" %j[0]
        hlplst = []
        for j in nd.nodes: # nd reference
            hlplst = hlplst + [j[0]]
        if snl not in hlplst:
            return "Node %s does not exist" %snl
        if enl not in hlplst:
            return "Node %s does not exist" %enl
        self.elements = self.elements + [[label, (snl, enl)]]
        self.elnum +=1
        self.ellen()

    def eldel(self, label):
        if self.elcheck(label) == False:
            return "Element %s does not exist!" %label
        for i in self.elements:
            if label == i[0]:
                self.elements.remove(i)
        self.elnum -=1

    def ellen(self):
        if self.elements == []:
            return "No elements defined!"
        for i in self.elements:
            if len(i) == 2:
                x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
                for j in nd.nodes:
                    if i[1][0] == j[0]:
                        x1 = j[1][0]
                        y1 = j[1][1]
                    elif i[1][1] == j[0]:
                        x2 = j[1][0]
                        y2 = j[1][1]
                i.append(round(hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2), 4))
            else:
                continue               

    def ellist(self):
        if self.elements == []:
            return "No elements defined!"
        print "\n"
        print "NUMBER OF ELEMENTS: ", self.elnum
        print "\n"
        print "ELEMENT   START NODE   END NODE   LENGTH    SECTION"
        print "-------   ----------   --------   ------    -------"
        print "\n"
        for i in self.elements:
            if len(i) < 4:
                print i[0], "          ", i[1][0], "          ", i[1][1], "      ", i[2], "      ", "NONE"
            else:
                print i[0], "          ", i[1][0], "          ", i[1][1], "      ", i[2], "      ", i[3]                

    def sctassign(self, label, slabel, elabel, dlabel):
        for i in s1.sections: # s1 reference
            if label == i[0]:
                break
            return "Section %s does not exist!" %label

        j = 0
        while slabel + j*dlabel <= elabel:
            for i in self.elements:
                if i[0] == slabel + j*dlabel:
                    i.append(label)
                    j += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    return "Element %e does not exist!" %(slabel + j*dlabel)
```

I put #nd reference inside the Element class where there seems to be a problem. Sorry, the code's a bit long...(the line where the #nd reference comment appears is the NameError line)

Comment: I don't get the connection between elgen and nd.nodes.  How would el.elgen know nd even existed, to access nd.nodes?  Is there some hidden global state?

Comment: The code of the other file is what's relevant, because it sounds like that's where the NameError is being generated (although it's a bit unclear.)  btw, `from foo import *` is a horrible idea.

Comment: Please post the code of the other file. It is necessary to avoid guesswork :)

Comment: Inserted code into first post.

Comment: @JohnKimble: I reiterate my question.  "nd" and "el" are names, labels you happened to give to a Node instance and an Element instance, but you refer to "nd.nodes" and "el.elements" from with the Element and Node classes.  I don't know what this would mean; what if there were two element instances called el1 and el2?  Which one should "for i in el.elements" pick?

Comment: @DSM: that's a good question, and I have already thought of it, but for now the instances will be unique. What I don't understand is why this code works if I run it, but when I run it from another module, it doesn't work. I.e. the references to the nd instance are not recognized outside this file for some reason. The point is: the nodegen procedure inside the Node class is supposed to create a list which has to be accessible to a procedure inside the Element class (elgen in this case). Perhaps there's a better way to do this? (perhaps I shouldn't bind these lists to the classes with self. ?)

Comment: By the way, at a later step I'll add another variable into the elgen procedure which tells what istance of Node to deal with - the point of this is to be able to process different groups of nodes, this may be quite handy at a later phase of the development of this program. The point is: I'd like to have this code separate and have a main module which uses defintions from this code for some kind of GUI, which I haven't yet started to work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood, because this seems straight forward. The name error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    el.elgen(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3)
  File "/home/snim2/Dropbox/scratch/so/fem_obj.py", line 86, in elgen
    for j in nd.nodes: # nd reference
NameError: global name 'nd' is not defined
```

and line 86 appears in this context:

```
def elgen(self, slabel, dlabel, snl, enl, sndl, endl, num):
    for i in range(1, num + 1):                
        label = slabel + (i - 1)*dlabel 
        if self.elcheck(label) == True:
            return "Element %s already exists!" %label
        if self.elements != []:
            for j in self.elements:
                if j[1] == (snl + (i - 1)*sndl, enl + (i - 1)*endl):
                    return "Element %s endnodes already taken!" %label
        hlplst = []
        for j in nd.nodes: # nd reference
            hlplst = hlplst + [j[0]]
        if snl + (i - 1)*sndl not in hlplst:
            return "Node %s does not exist" %(snl + (i - 1)*sndl)
        if enl + (i - 1)*endl not in hlplst:
            return "Node %s does not exist" %(enl + (i - 1)*endl)                             
        self.elements = self.elements + [[label, (snl + (i - 1)*sndl, enl + (i - 1)*endl)]]
        self.elnum +=1
    self.ellen()
```

So, if you want `elgen` to be able to use your array of `Node`s, you need to pass them into that method as an argument, like this:

```
def elgen(self, nd, slabel, dlabel, snl, enl, sndl, endl, num):
    for i in range(1, num + 1):                
        label = slabel + (i - 1)*dlabel 
        if self.elcheck(label) == True:
            return "Element %s already exists!" %label
        if self.elements != []:
            for j in self.elements:
                if j[1] == (snl + (i - 1)*sndl, enl + (i - 1)*endl):
                    return "Element %s endnodes already taken!" %label
        hlplst = []
        for j in nd.nodes: # nd reference
            hlplst = hlplst + [j[0]]
        if snl + (i - 1)*sndl not in hlplst:
            return "Node %s does not exist" %(snl + (i - 1)*sndl)
        if enl + (i - 1)*endl not in hlplst:
            return "Node %s does not exist" %(enl + (i - 1)*endl)                             
        self.elements = self.elements + [[label, (snl + (i - 1)*sndl, enl + (i - 1)*endl)]]
        self.elnum +=1
    self.ellen()
```

and in `main.py`:

```
nd = Node()
nd.nodegen(1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4)
el = Element()
el.elgen(nd, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3)
```

Comment: I edited the code and added "nd" as an argument to the procedures which use it. Now it seems to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go so far as to figure out everything that the code is supposed to be doing, however, you have the troubled line...

```
for j in nd.nodes: # nd reference
```

which refers to a variable "nd". I don't see where "nd" is defined, except in **main.py**. **main.py** is not going to be found. You can simplify this problem into the following errant code:

main.py:

```
 from feb_obj import run
 nd = "Test"
 run()
```

feb_obj.py:

```
 def run():
     print nd # This won't work!
```

I believe you're expecting it to know that "nd" is the variable defined in the "main.py" file. This is not how python works. "fem_obj.py" will only see what is defined within it's own scope. It knows what "hypot" and "sqrt" are because you imported them. However, it does not know about variables in other modules, including the main.py file.

Comment: Well, nd is defined inside the Nodes class, and in the main module, this is executed before the part where I'm referring to it. This is still a bit confusing to me - I'm not really sure im which namespace this variable is - obviously in the fem_obj module, since the main module can't see it.